# Running a report on a GA4 property using segments with google-analytics-api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I know that segments are not supported in the current v1Beta api ([https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/{property_id}:runReport](https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/%7Bproperty_id%7D:runReport)).

Is there a workaround to get segmented data from using this api?

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

Answer (score 0):

I was working with google analytics API GA4 using PHP hope this helps you

```
<?php
class analytics{
 private $property_id =null;
private $client = null;

   public $propertys;
public function setPropertyId($propertyid)
{
   return  $this->property_id = $propertyid;
}


private function getCredentials()
{
    return  DIR.'PATH/credentials.json');
}

private function getClient(): BetaAnalyticsDataClient
{
    return $this->client= new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
        'credentials' => $this->getCredentials(),
    ]);
}
 public function get($propertyid,$startdate,$enddate,dimensions,$metrics)
    {
        $response = $this->getClient()->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $this->setPropertyId($propertyid),
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' =>  $startdate,
                    'end_date' => $enddate,
                ]),
            ],
            'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
                [
                    'name' => $dimensions,
                ]
            ),
            ],
            'metrics' => [new Metric(
                [
                    'name' => $metrics,
                ]
            )
                ]
        ]);

    foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
        return $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();
    }
}
}
```

then you can use the get function with dates range and dimensions metrics you want